# How to solve error: the endpoint does not have a Binding with the None Message Version in WCF project?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on WCF. I have a website solution and I'd like to use WCF in it. When I call "http://---.com:83/Service.svc" this error appears:
The endpoint at 'http://---.com:83/Service.svc/mex' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

I don't know whats wrong in code!
config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehave">
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="endPointBehav" contract="IService"/>
    </service>
  </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehave">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endPointBehav">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

IService code:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    String DoWork();
}
```

Service.cs:

```
public class Service : IService
{
     [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    UriTemplate = "DoWork")]
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "done!";
    }
}
```

please note both of IService.cs and Service.cs are in App_Code folder in my solution. There is no any namespace name there to use in config file.

Comment: OOps. problem solved friends by changing endpoint tag in web.config to this format: <endpoint address="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="endPointBehav" contract="IService"/>

Comment: oh yeah. still error:  HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Service.svc/DoWork
I'm confused!

Comment: I solved it too :) I changed address="webHttp" to adress=""  in endpoint tag. If address="webHttp" then url should be: http://---.com:83/Service.svc/webHttp/DoWork